# Can the player that I stole art from see the stolen art in the trade screen?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm playing a multiplayer game and I've stolen a lot of art from one player. They don't know who's been stealing from them.

1. Can the victim see the art & artifacts I've stolen in the trade screen?
2. Can other players see the stolen art & artifacts in the trade screen?

I want to know whether I need to put an effort in to always be the one proposing trade deals, so other players don't scroll through my art as often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they can. I highly doubt they'll recognize the work of art as theirs, as most players simply acknowledge the existence of the work of art and not its name, but they can certainly check for the presence of one.

Comment: Be aware that you van check what Great People you earned and, hence, assume what Great Works are (were) yours.